# Overlaying Landsat 8 (raster) and shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, raster-conversion

[image: this is the failed overlay]

[image: downoladed landsat]

[image: Shapefile planned to use for extracting]

I would like to know what I can do correct such problem, those images are not overlaying while they have the same projection system.
I used even the extent of the shapefile to change the one for the Landsat but the problem is still available.

Comment: This is a variant of one of the most common questions in GIS SE. The general guideline to changing projections is *Don't do it* -- If the metadata is correct, you can only break it. If you have done a Define Projection when you meant to do a Project, it's time to roll back to the original source. If one of the sources is wrong, you need to make sure not to damage the right one with an incorrect Define.

Comment: How do you see their extent? I was thinking that they should be the same as well.

Comment: You have the extents shown, though if this is *after* you made changes, you need to [Edit] the Question to reflect the original metadata, and you should present the information as text, not an image.

Comment: Can you tell which one is correct?

Comment: the correct one is the "kirundo-P"